# Different parameter, violates normal form?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I started studying databases a week ago, and I have focuses on the relational model. I am pretty sure that is a dumb question, but is this relation valid? I suppose it isn't, but the tuples are not duplicated. Makes me doubt about it. Again forgive my ignorance.

```
 -------------------------------
|Name |  Number | Location |
 --------------------------------
| Mike   | 123      | New York  |
 --------------------------------
| Mike   | 564      | New York  |
 -------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by "valid?"

Comment: Well, I wonder if it violates the concept of relation.Which  is in least First Normal Form.

Comment: Is "Number" your primary index?  Are the two Mike's the same person?  More information is needed about your data.

Comment: Yes, both mike are same. And the address is same too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of tuples as presented satisfies 1NF trivially, but the only way to present the relation such that it doesn't do that is like so (violates atomicity):

```
 -------------------------------
| Name   |  Number  | Location  |
 --------------------------------
| Mike   | 123,564  | New York  |
 -------------------------------
```

Or like so (contains repeating groups):

```
 -------------------------------------------
| Name   |  NumberA |  NumberB | Location  |
 --------------------------------------------
| Mike   | 123      | 564      | New York  |
 -------------------------------------------
```

It's not really possible to go beyond that.  What's `Number`?  The address number?  The number of entities with `Name` of Mike?  A unique identifier?  What is `Location`?  Does it relate to `Name`, `Number`, or both?  If there's no unique key set of fields on the table, it technically violates 1NF since the table could allow duplicate rows.

Beyond that, the term "valid" and "invalid" aren't really defined terms for use with relational algebra.  The phrase commonly used is "violates normal form".  The only truly *invalid* relation is making one where one does not exist, like, say, a relation between the weight of an Oreo cookie and the number of stars in a given photograph.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect explanation